# Hmisc describe output when export as latex file giving API error 2

Tags: r, latex, hmisc

I am new to latex and I am trying to output the R results from `describe( )` function through `latex( )`.

A `.tex` file is being created but it is not giving me a **pdf** output

```
df = data.frame(A = rnorm(n = 100, 0,1)) %>% dplyr::mutate(B = 2*A+ runif(n = 100,-0.05,0.05))
# call latex( )
f = 'sample.tex'
df_latext = Hmisc::latex(describe(df,descript = 'Sample Description'), file = f)
```

When I run `df_latext` in the R console it is giving me the following error:

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

Data: path="C:\Users\domjo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpiYZcTM\file56f02ed47c3a.dvi"
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
Line: 301
MiKTeX: 22.8
OS: Windows 10.0.22000
Invokers: .../explorer/rstudio/rsession
SystemAdmin: no
Root0: C:\Users\domjo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
Root1: C:\Users\domjo\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
Root2: C:\Users\domjo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
UserInstall: C:\Users\domjo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
UserConfig: C:\Users\domjo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
UserData: C:\Users\domjo\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
```

Also, I tried running the `.tex` file created but its giving the following error saying **Environment spacing undefined.**:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment spacing undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                                                                             
l.1 \begin{spacing}{0.7}
?
```

Comment: From a TeXnical point of few, you'll probably need `\usepackage{setspace}` somewhere

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz can you run this from your end and see if you can replicate my error? I am getting two errors. One in latex file and one in R.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Why is it showing as `Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.` inside R? Do I have to pass any arguments into the `latex( )` function?

Comment: I'm not an R user. I would need to see your .tex file to test if it works

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uSovsxqj1T9l115yvxBz-kZ7DJrL1TSo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's only a code fragment, you can't run this .tex file. You'd need a documentclass, all the necessary packages etc.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I ran a similar code for a data frame in R and it worked when I added the following snippets of code: 
`\documentclass{article}\n\begin{document}\n` at the start 

`\end{document}\n` at the end

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I did not add any packages, but it worked. But when I do the same here, its not working